# Infinispan cache statistics: cache_size not working for clustered caches?

Tags: infinispan

We noticed that while for local caches we can get the actual **cache_size** (number of entries in the cache) statistics, for clustered caches (we tried **replicated-cache** and **invalidated-cache**) the value is always **-1**. Is that a known limitation or is there any way how to get these statistics to work?

Note that statistics are of course enabled for all these caches.

We can accept that the data wouldn't be accurate, but at least getting approximate values (that aren't way off) would be still useful.

Comment: do you mean `cache.size()` method return -1? which Infinispan version?

Comment: We use it via Spring Boot integration (embedded caches) where we gather stats via Spring's prometheus endpoint. I don't know how these stats are obtained but I suppose it's as you wrote. Infinispan 13.0.11, Spring Boot 2.7.4, Spring 5.3.23

Comment: There is a change since Infinispan 13 for size metrics. They need to be enabled in the cache container with <metrics accurate-size="true"/> or GlobalMetricsConfigurationBuilder accurateSize(boolean accurateSize)

Comment: Since you are using the Spring Boot integration, I believe we should fix the call of those statistics in the actuator integration too. There is the issue to follow https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-14282

Comment: @karesti So with that PR #10435 merged (hopefully it will make it into the 13.0.x branch as well) there should be at least an approximate size available even without setting the accurate-size?

Comment: @petrh I believe so, yes